# How to align 3 texts on the same base line?

Tags: html, css

What I have tried so far: http://cssdesk.com/zhc9c

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>FIRST</h1>
    <span class="second">This is second text</span>

    <span class="third">Third text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    position:relative;
}

h1 {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}

.second {
    margin-left:10px;
}

.third {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;bottom:10px;
}
```

The problems:

1. The third text doesn't seem to be aligned on the same base line with the others.
2. Because of I'm using absolute position that sets the bottom property (of the third text), it means if I change the bottom padding of the container, I need to set this property too. Is it possible to make it "automatically" adjusted?

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I allowed to add extra markup? If so, using [`inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) along with `vertical-align` is one possible solution:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>FIRST</h1>
    <span class="second">This is second text</span>
  </div><div>
    <span class="third">Third text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice there's no whitespace between the two `div` elements. This is because `inline-block` is affected by whitespace.

```
.container {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.container * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.container div {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: left;
}
.container div + div {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: right;
}
h1 {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
.second {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

See http://cssdesk.com/pghv7

Comment: This looks good but can you please explain what "div + div" does in css?

Comment: It's the Adjacent Sibling Selector. In this case it selects a `div` that immediately follows a `div` (`<div></div><div>it selects this one</div>)`. Another example might be `h1 + .second` which would select `.second` but only if it immediately follows an `h1`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: Thanks. This is new to me. Question: On the mozilla reference there is an example 

li + li {
  color: red;
}

Which changes the color of last two li's. Shouldn't it have changed the color of first two li's?

Comment: In that example, if you had `<ul><li>First one</li><li>Second one</li><li>Third one</li></ul>`, the second and third `li` elements would be `color: red;` because they immediately follow an `li` element. The first one follows a `<ul>`, so it would not be red.

Comment: Ok, this solution works. Thanks. Just curious, can it be done without extra div's? I'll try it anyway.

Comment: Well, forget my curiousity, extra div's work fine. But, after a close examination, it seems that the bottom of `h1` is not aligned to second text. When I change the font size of `h1` to bigger one, it looks obviously not aligned: http://cssdesk.com/MvNq8

Comment: There's two things at play here. First, remove the line height from the `h1` and things get a little closer. Now add some lower case letters with descenders (the little dangly bits on letters like g, y and j) and you can see why the space is there. Setting `line-height: 0.7;` on `.container` makes it line up again (for me), but that will probably be font-specific! See http://cssdesk.com/QuCes

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done without removing `position:absolute`. Using Absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal flow, so you'll need manual positioning.

Comment: If you have any solution without `position:absolute`, that's fine for me.

Comment: Olly's answer is perfect! Use that. Use `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

```
.third {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:20px;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

You can use this. It is setting the text at the approx position.

Comment: How do I know the height? if I change the `font-size` of `h1`, do I need to change the height too?

Comment: If you are using `h1` tag then there is no need of height property http://cssdesk.com/wJdt6 but if you are using `span` then you should give height.